# Copy/paste from ubuntu to ubuntu RDP via putty

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, putty, remmina

I am connecting from my Ubuntu to my work desktop through remmina on my Windows partition, and through my Windows partition to the Ubuntu one through Putty.
I can't copy paste text from my local text files to the command line inside my remote Ubuntu which makes my work very impractical.
Is there a way to activate that function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not entirely clear to and from are you connecting but it seems to be a problem or limitation of Putty, a Windows software, therefore unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: I am trying to copy from local ubuntu to remote ubuntu where I have connected via Putty. Thanks!

Comment: Again, Putty is Windows software. Why and how are you using it to remotely connect an Ubuntu from another Ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah I undestand. It is the only way we have currently been provided in order to connect to our remote Ubuntu parition. Local ubuntu to remote WIndows through remmina and remote Windows to remote ubuntu though Putty. I know it's not the ideal way but I currently don't have another option.